# Why is this expression not callable, if it is only initialized in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
let callback1: null | (() => void) = () => {};
let callback2: null | (() => void) = null;
let callback3: null | (() => void) = null;

if (callback1 != null)
    callback1(); // callable

callback2 = () => {}
if (callback2 != null)
    callback2(); // callable

new Promise<void>(() => callback3 = () => {});

if (callback3 != null)
    callback3(); // not callable
    // ^^^
    // This expression is not callable.
    //     Type 'never' has no call signatures.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAxghswCMZQNYEYBcEB2BXeEAPhABQkCUEAvAHwQBuA9gJYAmlVpHdA3gL4BuALAAoUJFjwkqAExY8BYmW4MW7ajnzBhY8NDiJkKAMzytRUhWp0mbDpvg7RzAGalJh1GggBCTguByUQgQ-SkjNAoBCAB6GLDgGARQUVEPaRQZDStaCH5nNxJ0oyy-B0Dg0OLZKNj4jySUkVFsEAB3CAAFACdGAFtmAGcQAB5bVhplawSM42yVfnInEVd3A1nffy0gkVCZo2NauJxGCQNGkEqQ44A9O6u6iAAVAAshiBAADwAHbpBBwbMRjYCDvbCnBIXAB0D2OeyeAE9viAIAByVr0EDdVEQF4wQYnBIQQEAc2wMDAuD+gyhQA)

It seems like TypeScript is doing some static analysis, but wrongly, as the code works fine in JS:

```
let callback3 = null;
new Promise(() => callback3 = () => { console.log("It Works"); });
if (callback3 != null)
    callback3();

// output: It Works
```

Comment: "but wrongly," I'd prefer to call it "correctly, since it cannot guarantee this is going to hold true in the general case". Consider if `new Promise<void>(() => callback3 = () => {});` was instead `setTimeout(() => callback3 = () => {});`

Comment: @VLAZ If it can't with 100% certainly rule out the possibility of `() => void`, which I explicitly declared, it has no business discarding it.

Comment: Well, this is a...feature. Although I'd agree it does get in the way some times. It considers the variable *effectively* a constant, since, even though it's a `let`, it's only assigned once. ...if you ignore the callback that also sets it, since TS cannot guarantee it happens synchronously. The effectively a constant thing works in some cases but I still consider it awkward in many others. Some times I just want to prototype some code and use something like `let x: string | number = 42;` and since it's effectively a constant, TS yells at me for treating it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you init `callback3` with a literal `null` and you don't modify it, TS infers its type as `null`.

with `if (callback3 != null)` you're [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) it down to `never` hence the error.

This doesn't happen in this kind of case :

```
declare const maybeCallback: null | (() => void);

callback3 = maybeCallback;

if(callback3 !== null) {
    // () => void not never
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAxghswCMZQNYEYBcEB2BXeEAPhABQkCUEAvAHwQBuA9gJYAmlVpHdA3gL4BuALAAoUJFjwkqAExY8BYmW4MW7ajnzBhY8NDiJkKAMzytRUhWp0mbDpvg7RzAGalJh1GggBCTguByUQgQ-SkjNAoBCAB6GLDgGARQUVEPaRQZDStaCH5nNxJ0oyy-B0Dg0OLZKNj4jySUkVFsEAB3CAAFACdGAFtmAGcQAB5bVhplawSM42yVfnInESqDWdE4iAA9AH4IVJFXdzWjObKAoJXV8NRjWs3sRgkDRpBKkM2tr-e6iAAVAAWQwgIAAHgAHbogQaDZiMbAQYGPZ7wV4AOh%20m1C-wAnuCQBAAOSteggbqEiAAmCDHCMBIQWEAc2wMDAuChgwxzRErBAUESUOg8MGkD6MBxCBAAGETqgzIpLCpxksDtUTBoxRLpbKUMtXEUdWcqP4tJQeD81XdKJtGChRHwgA)

Comment: This is not exactly the same though. My doing `declare const`, `maybeCallback` is undefined, not null. Which makes the type definition wrong.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev you're thinking in terms of runtime not type checking. My answer is only about type checking.